# Knockout.js Textbox Value Binding Auto-Complete

Tags: autocomplete, knockout.js, internet-explorer-9

I have a text input field bound to a viewmodel using a Knockout.js value binding. In IE9 if I type in the first few letters of my username, I get the standard auto-complete dropdown. Selecting my username from the auto-complete does not update my viewmodel. Is there a way to trigger an update to my observable from an auto-complete selection?

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: userName" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was submitted as a bug 1 year ago:

https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/122

It seems a fix been included in the 2.1.0 version of knockout.js - so if you update it should fix this issue for you.

If this is not possible, an alternative suggestion is to just turn autocomplete off on your username `<input>` using the attribute `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Updating to 2.1.0 seems to have fixed the issue. Interestingly in IE9 it seems to have disabled autocomplete altogether which works fine for my need.

Answer (score 7):

Upgrading to 2.1.0 as suggested by Richard's answer fixed my problem, so I have marked it as the answer.

For anyone needing this to work in Knockout 2.0.0, setting valueUpdate to 'blur' seems to work as well.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: userName, valueUpdate: 'blur'" />
```

Comment: This fixed my issue for jQuery/KO autocomplete textboxes.  InputText binding did not appear to play well with my version of autocomplete drop downs. Thanks!

Comment: With IE11, the original issue seems to be back. Your solution fixed the problem partially. I said partially since you have to click one additional click  outside the text input to update the viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me valueUpdate: 'blur' with ko_autocomplete in knockout